# global variable in parent and children processes

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, process

Question about processes dynamic pool. I need to keep information of free processes. If count of free processes will be less than `N`, I should  create new processes. But,I know that `free` variable will be the same in every process. How to make `free` variable "global" and changing in child processes will change variable in parent, and then parent can check this and make more children processes? Something like shared memory and other IPC. Little confused with them.

```
 free=5;
 for (i=0;i<5;i++) // create 5 pre-forks
   { 
        pid=fork();
        if (pid==0) //child
        { 
            break;
        }
        else//parent
        { 

        }
    }

    while (1) 
    {
        if (pid==0) // child
        {
             newsock = accept(listensock, NULL,NULL);
             free--; //children is busy
             send(newsock, buffer, nread, 0); 
             close(newsock);
             free++;
        }
        else if (pid>0) // parent
        {
            if ...// if less than n fork() more
        }
    }
```

Comment: You answered your own question.  You could use shared memory.  Just look up documentation on shared memory online.  If you want to share address space between running entities, use threads.  If you use threads, they can share shared memory safely if you use a mutex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you can use shared memory to store a variable shared between different processes. One of the processes must create that shared memory with `shmget`

shmget needs a key to identify the shared memory region, the size, and some additional options. The common options for create are `IPCCREAT | 0666` to create it with unix permissions 0666

The other processes call `shmget` with 0 as the last parameter to use the already initializated segment.

To connect the process direction space with the shared memory you must use `shmat`

Example:

```
#define KEY ((key_t) 1234)  //Any value, just dont overlap other applications in the machine
#define SIZE sizeof(int)

int* free;

int id = shmget(KEY, SIZE, IPCCREAT | 0666);
if (id < 0) //Error...

free = (int*) shmat(id, 0, 0);
if (free <= (int*)(0)) // shmat failed...

//At this point, you can use free as a normal variable
*free = 5;
*free++;
...
//As various processes can access free, you must use any control mechanism (mutex, semaphores...)

shmdt(id); //Unlink shared memory segment
```

Comment: You really ought to use the POSIX `shm_open()` instead. It's easier to use and is unlikely to have key collisions.

Comment: shared memmory is hard variant, can it be solved using pipe()?

Comment: @NatKup A pipe is an unidirectional connection between two processes. You have N processes with bidirectional comunication, if you dont use threads, shared memory is the way to go.

Comment: Can you please write this code with my code?
it's very hard to understand how to use that with my code. Please.